# Change Color of Stacked Grouped Google Column Chart

Tags: google-visualization

Please look at http://jsfiddle.net/v1u1afzn/228/

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
  'packages': ['bar']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    ['2001', 321, 600, 816, 319],
    ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594],
    ['2003', 125, 819, 123, 578],
    ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 298]
  ]);

  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 1100,
        min: 0
      }
    },
    vAxes: {
      0: {
      },
      1: {
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        textStyle: {
          color: 'transparent'
        }
      },
    },
    series: {
      2: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
      3: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
    },
    colors: ['blue', 'red'],
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

How do I change the faded / lighter blue (first column top stack) to say yellow?

I cannot find a way to change color of individual series that is grouped.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `series` option to change the color of an individual series / column / stack

```
series: {
  0: {
    color: 'yellow'
  },
  1: {
    color: 'green'
  },
  2: {
    color: 'blue',
    targetAxisIndex: 1
  },
  3: {
    color: 'red',
    targetAxisIndex: 1
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    ['2001', 321, 600, 816, 319],
    ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594],
    ['2003', 125, 819, 123, 578],
    ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 298]
  ]);

  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 1100,
        min: 0
      }
    },
    vAxes: {
      1: {
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        textStyle: {
          color: 'transparent'
        }
      },
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        color: 'yellow'
      },
      1: {
        color: 'green'
      },
      2: {
        color: 'blue',
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
      3: {
        color: 'red',
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**note:** `jsapi` should no longer be used to load the charts library,
according to the release notes...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. The last update, for security purposes, was with a pre-release of v45. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...